# Choosing N changing points in a sorted list

Tags: python, list

Imagine we have a sorted list with size P. How can we choose N indices for which the values reflect the range of the list more smoothly. For example if our list is:

```
List=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.91,0.91,0.92,0.99,0.99,0.99]
```

Then how we choose let's say 5 indices that somehow shows the full range of the list?
In this example it would be something like :

```
indices=[0,9,11,14,15]
```

The final indices list doesn't have to be exactly like the one I wrote here though

Comment: could your provide more details and a code sample of what you currently have?

Comment: @EmettSpeer I don't have anything now.

Comment: @PaulRooney Not really. Because the values could change very slightly sometime and you can only choose N point so you waste some indices if you choose them inappropriately.

Comment: @PaulRooney That's the problem. How do you choose the correct delta value?

Comment: Is this a curve fitting problem? Use some math maybe?

Comment: Do you want to choose `N` indices such that change around those indices falls in the `N` largest values?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a starting point:

```
[List.index(x) for x in set(List)]
```

Now this may have too many elements but "somehow" is totally subjective and not a clear enough definition for what you need to do. As a default you can keep the first and last element, then randomly pick as many as you require from the "middle".

Comment: And then if the OP wants that result to be ordered (since sets are unordered), we can call `sorted()` on that list comprehension.